# How does this function call work? (Involves multiple pairs of brackets and decorators)

Tags: python

On this page of the official Python documentation about decorators and 'compound statements', this sample of code is given:

[Begin of sample]

```
@f1(arg)
@f2
def func(): pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def func(): pass
func = f1(arg)(f2(func))
```

[End of sample]

However, I don't understand 'func = f1(arg)(f2(func))'. I've never seen a call like this before, and I have no idea of what it means. Is it multiple calls using different arguments, each pair of brackets containing one argument ('arg' in the first, 'f2(func)' in the second), or is it something else? I need to understand this in order to be able to study decorators. Also, does this work in Python 2.7? One of the sites I consulted on decorators was about Python 3.2.

Comment: Decorators should still work in python 2.7 -- I'm not aware of them changing anything with decorators between python 2.7 and 3.x (though I could be wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to know for this is that functions are first class objects - you can pass functions around just like `int`s or `str`s.

`f1` returns a function, so what you've posted is similar to:

```
def func(): pass
f1_ret = f1(arg)
f2_ret = f2(func)
func = f1_ret(f2_ret)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of a Python function call is a value like any other. If you want, you can write `func = f1(arg)(f2(func))` as

```
def func(): pass
x = f2(func)
y = f1(arg)
func = y(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

A decorator that takes arguments must *return* a function that does the actual decorating. So `@f1(arg)` calls `f1(arg)`. `f1` returns a function, which can be called using the usual `(...)` notation: `f1(arg)(...)`. What goes in the second set of parentheses? The function being decorated, which is `f2(func)` because of the second decorator. So put it all together and you get `f1(arg)(f2(func))`.

The piece you're missing, then, is that `f1` returns a function and the second set of parentheses are calling the returned function.